# Find Line in skeleton Images OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following picture:

[image]

and I want to find the lines to do some calculations, average length etc ...
I tried to use `HoughLinesP`, but it doesn't find the lines. How can I do?

This is my code:

```
sk=skeleton(mask);
rows, cols = sk.shape
imgOut=np.zeros((rows,cols,3),np.uint8)
imgOut[:,:,0]=0
imgOut[:,:,1]=0
imgOut[:,:,2]=0


minLineLength = 0
maxLineGap = 0

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(sk,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(imgOut,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

print len(lines[0])

cv2.imshow('skel',sk)
cv2.imshow('Line',imgOut)
cv2.imwrite('Out.bmp',imgOut)
```

Output:

[image]

If i change the parameters of `HoughLinesP` I only get fragments of line, not a solid line.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: Dude, these are not straight lines, these are curves. [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) says `The Hough Line Transform is a transform used to detect straight lines.` So, no matter how you change the parameters, you won't be able to detect them with this approach.

Answer (score 6):

Although the Hough lines algorithm is meant for lines only (and you're clearly dealing with curves), there might be a way to salvage your attempt, by greatly augmenting the `rho` and `theta` parameters.

This should make the curved sides point to the same bin rather than be split in different bins.

---

**EDIT** : 
You have a bit of a problem : OpenCV's definition of `cv2.HoughLinesP`. From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cv2.houghlinesp#cv2.HoughLinesP) :

> cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]])

As you might see, the 5th parameter is `lines`, the output variable.
Your call is

```
cv2.HoughLinesP(sk,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   lines
```

So your given `minLineLength` parameter has no effect (it becomes an output variable), and `maxLineGap` has wrong interpretation too.

I suggest to explicitly write parameter names (without parameter tweaks yet)

```
cv2.HoughLinesP(sk.astype(np.uint8),rho=1,theta=np.pi/180,threshold=100,
                minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=maxLineGap)
```

a bit long to write, but at least OpenCV doesn't mix the parameters anymore

#### Visualizing the lines

I changed the line color for each line for an easier time visualizing which segment is where :

```
    color = np.random.uniform(0,255,3)
    cv2.line(imgOut,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),color,2)
```

#### Changing parameters

By having less bins for `rho` and `theta` (achieved by increasing the parameters) you will have more chances of having the edges of a curve vote for the same line-bin.

Here are some attempts (full code below)

```
rho=5,theta=np.deg2rad(10),threshold=10,minLineLength=5,maxLineGap=2
```

[image: Too many lines]
Too many lines shown. Lowering the parameters

### Why skeletonize ?

Your input image (as given) looks like edges are already there. The output of `skeletonize` is only the central line of edges, which sounds like a positive thing, but for Hough Lines, it means reducing the number of pixels "voting" for line segments.

```
# sk = skeletonize(mask==255)
sk = mask==255
```

This didn't change much in specifics, but I thought it couldn't hurt the task at hand.

## Why not label ?

What you're trying to get is individual line segments. Why not just label the image ?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage 

labels,nblabels = ndimage.label(sk)
plt.imshow(labels,'jet')
plt.show()
```

[image: Labelled image]

By applying a little morphological operators you will get individual lines or in the worst case, line branchings.

Now you can select the lines individually by doing

```
line = labels == 2 # select the pixels with label 2 only
```

Applying Hough lines to these might be overkill to untangle them, but you'd have significantly broken down your problems already.

Calculation of metrics is now super easy (see [ndimage.measurement](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.measurements) documentation) and iteration over arrays is super simple.

Comment: ok, the starting image is bad, but also using a better picture, i not get acceptable results, the lines that I have to take are not exactly straight, are slightly curved.

If change the values of theta and rho i get 287 lines. I have to post-process the resulting array to merge the segments ?

Comment: Nah, this is what the `maxLineGap` and `minLineLength` are there for. I am fiddling with your code right now, I'll edit my answer with more info soon

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've been working on and yours is a great idea, but in this way I can not isolate the lines that overlap, because basically I have to identify the lines "almost" straight.
I have to try finding the endpoints in the skeletonized image and checking if there are line between two point. What do you think?