# cv2.HoughLinesP on a skeletonized image

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying to detect lines in a certain image. I run it through a skeletonization process before applying the cv2.HoughLinesP. I used the skeletonization code [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.de/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html).

[image: Skeleton]

No matter what I try I keep getting results similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146296/find-line-in-skeleton-images-opencv-python) i.e. 'only fragments of a line..'

[image: Houghlines overlayed on the object]

[image: Fragmented lines]

As suggested by Jiby, I use the named notation for the parameters and also high rho and theta, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(skel, rho=5, theta=np.deg2rad(10), threshold=0, minLineLength=0, maxLineGap=0)
```

Prior to this I threshold a RGB image to extract most of my 'blue' hollow rectangle. Then I convert it to gray scale which I then feed to the skeletonizer.

Please advise.

Comment: Please attach a sample picture to see what you're trying to attempt to do.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Hey, did you have a look at the images?